# no grub menu for 11.10 and 12.04LTS

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, grub2

I'm already on 11.10 and out of curiosity I installed 12.04 on a separate partition. But when I boot up my machine, it is going into 11.10. It doesn't show up grub menu to select which OS I want to boot into.

While installing from 12.04, I selected the option 'something else' and installed 12.04 on a separate partition.

any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: did you try keep pressed `Alt` when turned on your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quite simple. It would seem that GRUB is simply installed incorrectly.

You could first try opening a terminal and running `sudo update-grub`

If that doesn't solve the problem, run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (if you get an error, replace sda with hda), and then run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: It worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you installed grub record of the ubuntu 12.04 onto boot sector of that separate partition.

If I am correct, then you need to chainload the boot sector of that partition (with 12.04) from MBR of the disk.

Add to the end of /etc/grub.d/40_custom the following lines and run update-grub:

## for ubuntu 12.04 on sda5

title ubuntu 12.04
root (hd0,4)
chainloader +1

You can also go without editing the grub files, by booting into grub menu and typing the chainloading instructions over there.